# How secure is URL rewriting?

Tags: security, mod-rewrite

This is possibly a duplicate question, but I am unable to find the other one if it is.

I was looking for advice on how secure url rewriting is? Does it stop SQL injection, or XSS? If not, how would one circumvate it?

The reason I ask is because I am unsure of the process that rewriting takes. Am I right in believing that this URL could effectively be dangerous:

http://www.website.com/article/1' UNION ALL...

Comment: I don't see what it has to do with SQL injection or XSS.

Comment: This question would be more valuable for the community if you explained what aspects or URL rewriting make you think that could help in those issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

URL rewriting doesn't have anything to do with preventing SQL injections! URL rewriting is mostly used to turn "ugly" URLS (like http://domain.com/index.php?name=1&value=2) into pretty URLs like http://domain.com/1/2).

It doesn't prevent SQL injection at all. SQL injection must be prevented by making sure that user inputs do not contain characters that modify an SQL statement so that it does things that were not intended. Example:

You have an SQL Statement like:

```
SELECT * FROM $tableName;
```

And `$tableName` is a parameter that is entered by the user through a web form. Now the user could enter `Users; DROP TABLE Users; --`. This would be bad:

```
SELECT * FROM Users; DROP TABLE Users; --;
```

This, however, can not be solved by URL rewriting.

Comment: So am I right in thinking that if unsanitized this could be dangerous? http://www.website.com/article/1' UNION ALL...

Comment: You should understand that SQL injection is not limited to bad URL parameters. While there may be conditions where URL parameters that are not sanitized can lead to unexpected and unwanted results in SQL statements, URL parameters are by far not the only thing that may lead to unexpected results. As a general rule: Anything that doesn't come from within your code (for example URL parameters, POST parameters, user inputs, etc.) must be sanitized - but URL *rewriting* won't help you at all.

Answer (score 1):

no, URL rewrite couldn't prevent XSS or SQL Injection.

If you want to avoid SQL Injection, use DBI Library (with prepare/execute statement) in your code.

If you want to avoid XSS Attack, please filter your user input in your code, too.

Answer (score 1):

URL rewriting and security are two different things. The URL rewrite simply changes the presentation of variables in the url but does not secure at all. We must secure the variables in your code after you recover from the url.

Answer (score 0):

But for SQL Injection based only on the $_GET variable, if we use this:

RewriteRule ^([a-z]*)-([0-9]*).html$ /index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L]

Is the $_GET["id"] variable injectable? We are forcing the value with only integer.

Answer (score 0):

URL rewriting has feature called 'Request blocking'. You can use this feature to scan and prevent 3rd party tools sending spoof requests.